# How can I set raster outliers in QGIS to nodata?

Tags: qgis, gdal, raster-calculator, saga, nodata

for further analysis I want to execlude raster outliers (mostly single pixel values).

Therefore, how can I set global raster outliers (e.g., `mean +- 2*sd`) to nodata value in QGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use gdal raster calculator with the formula:

`where( (mean(A)-(2*std(A))<A) & (A<mean(A)+(2*std(A))), A, -999)`

"where the raster value is between mean - 2*std and mean + 2*std": use raster value,
"if not set it to -999"

Then set "output nodata value to -999".

Change -999 to something else if your raster can have values of -999.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks BERA for this answer! This is exactly I was looking for; and even available to batch mode! 
Can you say something about the backgrounds of normal Raster Calculator vs GDAL raster calculator?